# Starting more than one Service in foreground

Tags: android, android-service

I have some android [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)s in my project. Considering that I did't configure anyone to work in a different processes, what happens if I try to run two or more services in foreground mode? I'll try to explain better my doubt.
If all the Services are in the same process, maybe should be enough starting just one of them in foreground, and then every Service will not be killable, because the entire process should stay alive. Because, actually the process will be considered a *Foreground process* since, as [explained here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html), it has the following condition:

> It hosts a Service that's running "in the foreground"—the service has
>   called startForeground().

So basically the question is:

*Does the start of a service in foreground guarantee that all the services in the same process will not be killed?*

Comment: I am not really sure about this, I don´t think another foreground service of your app gets killed by an existing one. But you can give it a try, because a foreground service needs to have a notofication. So, logical, there must be two different icons in the notification bar if you start two services. If you see both, you know it´s not killed....

Comment: And there is never a guarantee that any service stays alive, even foreground services can be killed. They just got a higher priority and only get killed if resources are needed and only get killed after enough backgroundservices are killed....

Comment: Yes, but what actually I'm interested in, is to know if start a foreground service is enough for avoiding other services in the same process to be killed. And, of course, I know that there is never guarantee that any series stay always alive